# How to call a javascript function using Twitter´s Bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I want to use the javascript provided in Tritter´s Bootstrap. I´ve checked that all the .js files are pointed out ok.

I want to test if it works ok, so after reading the [docs](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#tooltips), I understand that I have to "call" the appropiate javascript function?

> Using bootstrap-tooltip.js
>   Trigger the tooltip via javascript: $('#example').tooltip(options)

How may I call that function? It seems that it´s not enough to put the proper html, I have to call the function aswell?

Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Give a HTML element the ID of `example` and appropriate attributes like this:

```
<p><a href="#" rel="tooltip" title="first tooltip" id="example">hover over me</a>,/p>
```

In your `<head>` create a JavaScript `<script>` element, make sure jQuery is loaded and then, within the jQuery, add the tooltip to the element with the ID of `example`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function()
    {
        if(!window.jQuery)
        {
            alert('jQuery not loaded');
        }
        else
        {
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('#example').tooltip({'placement':'top', 'trigger' : 'hover'});
            });
        }
    }
</script>
```

This will setup a tooltip when you hover over the `#example` element. Change `top` to `left`, `right` or `bottom` to change where the tooltip is placed in relation to the element itself.

---

In case you might want to in the future, this is how you'd set up a popover also.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed reply! I´ve tried it but it doesn´t worked. I think it might be something related to the links? I´ve added inside my head: <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script> and <script src="https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/master/js/bootstrap-tooltip.js"></script> (instead of the bootstrap file that I´ve got in my own folder) but it won´t work, could I´ve missed something else?

Comment: Load the JavaScript files before the end of the `<body>` tag. Look at the source code of the [documentation](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#popovers). Check your `bootstrap/js` folder for `jquery.js`, `bootstrap-tooltip.js` and `bootstrap.js` and if you don't follow the links to them in the [documentation source code](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#popovers) and save them 3 files to the `bootstrap/js` folder (at least 3! I have them all so I'm not sure which exactly you need).